# Jquery slider handle should pulse colors

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I am trying to see if I can make a jquery slider handle stand out more.

http://jsfiddle.net/QAuNY/

So I am trying to use the preceding code, only I am not sure the `flashing` event is every happening.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a jsfiddle that does the "pulsation".
[Link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/CgSjL/3/)

```
$(function () {
    $("#secrets-slider").slider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        value: 70,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#amount").val(ui.value);
        }
    });
    function flashing() {
        if (flash === 0) {
            $("#secrets-slider .ui-slider-range").stop(true, true);
        } else {
            $("#secrets-slider").animate(
                {
                    backgroundColor: '#ff8c00'
                }, 500,
                function() {
                    $("#secrets-slider").animate(
                        {
                            backgroundColor: '#f00'
                        }, 500
                    )
                }                                         
            )
            setTimeout(flashing,1000);
        }
    }
    flashing();
});
```

Due to the fact that jQueryUI uses background images for drawing the slider, some parts of the slider remains grey - but they are controllable through your css theme.

Comment: That seems to work, thanks.  Slighty updated to what I wanted at http://jsfiddle.net/CgSjL/4/